# Cross-Domain iframe Resizer on NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js, iframe-resizer

I have a NextJS project that will be loaded through an Iframe. The content of the page is dynamic and the height of the page constantly changes. Instead of using scroll, I want the Iframe to adjust its height according to its content's height.

I have tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer-react but it seems I have an issue on how to load the iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js.

Need help, Can't find any other answers/sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that file to every page you load into the iFrame

Comment: Hi @david-bradshaw, just to ask: do you recommend adding it explicitly on the pages or does adding the script on `_app.js` work?

Comment: I’m not sure which framework your using there. If it is a single page app, once is enough

Comment: I'm also using Next.js, thus the question. Vercel recommends using `_document.js` to load scripts but I haven't been able to make it work. :sad: I might go the route of really adding it on every page as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the contentWindow script from the iframe resizer to your component, and set the callback *(if needed)*

```
import "iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function Component() {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.iFrameResizer = {
      onMessage: function (message) {
        alert('Got message from parent');
        console.log('message', message);
      },
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>Your content</div>;
}

export default Component;
```

iframe resizer does require the window so make sure it only runs on the client by importing the component using next/dynamic

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const Component = dynamic(() => import("components/Component"), {
  ssr: false,
})

function Page(props) {
  return <Component {...props} />
}

export default Page;
```